# sql server 2012 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I know there are many posts about the error message *"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"* but I couldn't find out why I get the error.

I have a table (let's call it `MyTable`) that has a varchar(255) column `Filename`. Every filename has a date portion in it. For example:

```
[Filename]
-----------------
FILE-160105_1.CSV
FILE-160105_2.CSV
FILE-160106_1.CSV
FILE-160106_2.CSV
...
```

My task is to get the date part out of the filenames and filter the resultset to a specific range of dates. The first step works fine

```
  SELECT Convert(date, SUBSTRING([Filename],6,6), 12) AS dat
  FROM mytable
```

and I get a correct result without errors:

```
dat
----------
05.01.2016
05.01.2016
06.01.2016
06.01.2016
```

But now, when I put the SELECT-Statement above in a common table expression and filter the `dat` column, I get the error as shown. The complete code which queries the base table in the database is as follows:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT Convert(date, SUBSTRING([Filename],6,6), 12) AS dat
  FROM dbo.myTable
)
SELECT dat
FROM CTE
WHERE dat = Convert(date,'160105',12);
```

What I do not understand is, why the SELECT in the CTE gives me a result set, converted as date but the outer query tries to convert something.

Because I could not find the error, I thought, I could use another CTE to generate the same data as in `MyTable` for testing. And the funny part is: The following example works, but when I query the basetable directly, an error is thrown. Why?

```
WITH mytable as
(
  SELECT [Filename] FROM (VALUES ('FILE-160105_1.CSV'), ('FILE-160105_2.CSV'), ('FILE-160106_1.CSV'),
                                ('FILE-160106_2.CSV')) AS Files([Filename])
)
, CTE AS
(
  SELECT Convert(date, SUBSTRING([Filename],6,6), 12) AS dat
  FROM mytable
)
SELECT dat
FROM CTE
WHERE dat = Convert(date,'160105',12);
```

This gives me the correct result:

```
dat
---------
05.01.2016
05.01.2016
```

It would be great if someone could help me. Thanks.
PS: By the way: the session language in SQL-Server is set to us_english

> ******** UPDATE ******

In the comments there is an advice to use TRY_CAST. When I run the following code, SQL Server Returns no error. I get the result with all rows:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT Convert(date, SUBSTRING([Filename],6,6), 12) AS dat
  FROM dbo.MyTable
  WHERE [Filename] LIKE 'FILE-%'
)
SELECT dat, TRY_CAST(dat as date) as trydat
FROM CTE
```

When I look through the rows manually there are no NULLs in the column `trydat` so the CAST was successful. BUT, when I put TRY_CAST in the WHERE Clause to filter the dat column the Statement Fails:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT Convert(date, SUBSTRING([Filename],6,6), 12) AS dat
  FROM dbo.MyTable
  WHERE [Filename] LIKE 'FILE-%'
)
SELECT dat
FROM CTE
WHERE TRY_CAST(dat as date) = '20160106';
```

I think there is something wrong with the table. When I create a new table and query it, there are no conversion problems.

Comment: You must have some rows in your table that can't be cast to a date. The sample data you provided will NOT reproduce this error.

Comment: `SELECT name, collation_name FROM sys.databases;` Share default collation for your DB

Comment: @Sean Lange But the convert Statement produces no error.

Comment: You could try a select try_cast as the table variable and select from it where dat is null.

Comment: @lad2025: The Default collation is: Latin1_General_CI_AS

Comment: @user2538042     I added an example for TRY_CAST and have updated my post. It Looks like SQL Server is scanning different structures for SELECT and WHERE.

Comment: Bear in mind that different queries may use different paths to get to similar results. For example, it's perfectly valid for SQL Server to look through *all* the dates in your `MyTable` and *then* trim down the results to those `WHERE [Filename] LIKE 'FILE-%'`. Or it might do it the other way round, trimming the results based on `WHERE [Filename] LIKE 'FILE-%'` (which could perhaps exclude all invalid dates) and *then* do the date conversion. The query optimiser will decide which path seems best at every run of the code.

Comment: (So, what happens if you try your `TRY_CAST` with no other filtering, i.e. without the `WHERE [Filename] LIKE 'FILE-%'`? Do you see any NULLs in the results then? Because you need to consider the possibility that SQL Server will do the date conversion for every date in your data *before* it does any other filtering to get the results you asked for.)

Comment: @Matt Gibson   I knew that the quey optimizer can re-order the steps for more optimal query-processing. Your commend gave me an idea to use APPLY instead. So your answer is correct.  Thank you very much. I will post the code that works for me now in my question above

Comment: If you've basically answered your own question with a hint or two from me, you should post your answer as an actual answer. There's no problem answering your own question here.

Answer (score 1):

The hint from Matt Gibsons comment gave me the idea to re-write the query and use the APPLY-Operator instead.

The query works now with the SQL-Statement

```
SELECT [Filename], A1.dat
FROM dbo.MyTable
OUTER APPLY (SELECT Convert(date, SUBSTRING([Filename],6,6), 12)) AS A1(dat)
WHERE [Filename] LIKE 'FILE-%'
  AND A1.dat = '20160120'
```

I think for the original-query the optimizer decides to first `CAST AS date` and then filter the rows with `[Filename] LIKE 'FILE-%'`.

This doesn't work because in the table are different filenames where the date is at different positions. But those I didn't want to query.